# Do document oriented databases need more space because they have to save all the keys?

Tags: document-oriented-db, bigdata

I want to use a document oriented database for saving statistics (big data) and want to know if this is a good idea.

Comment: More space than what? This question is too vague to answer currently.

Comment: @Bathsheba Than relational databases for example

Comment: Document-oriented databases use a completely different system to save the data than relational databases. The sizes of the databases aren't different because of the existence of keys in the documents.

Answer (score -1):

Yes relational database takes more space than nosql database but mostly because NOSQL uses non normalized schema design.